# What presentation software could have been used to make this video?

Tags: windows-xp, presentations

What software do you think was used to create [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwNgNyiXPLk) video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link to the author's website and reading the FAQs, I found this "Chris created the Crash Course in his home office using Powerpoint for the slides, Camtasia Pro for the video, and Audacity for the audio."